# Monoprice i3 clone heat shuts off printing abs

Tags: extruder, heated-bed, abs

I have the Monoprice Select 3D Printer (i3 clone). I'm trying to print ABS. I set the temperature to 230°C for the extruder and 110°C for the bed. I can see the printer warming up to those temperatures and then when it gets there the bed and extruder set temperatures reset to 0, and the print does not start.

I pulled the ABS out and went back to PLA and printed a part without any issues.

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Comment: Does it shut down the temperatures before reaching the demanded values? Or close to these values? Not many heat beds reach 110°C due to bad connectors/connections, thin wires or lack of insulation at the bottom side.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that it shuts down before reaching the 110c.

I was playing with the extruder temperatures. I was at 250c and bumped it up to 260c. It must have thought something was wrong and it set the temp to 0c. Unfortunately, it keeps printing.

I made a quick and dirty enclosure with a few pieces of cardboard and then was able to get up to 110C for the bed and 255c for the extruder.

So I guess I'm building an enclosure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be connected to a thermal shutdown protection.
Most firmwares requires a decent increase in temperature every few seconds.

if you use Marlin then in the source code you can extend thermal shutdown timings.

what to check:
**check every single connector to eliminate any fiddling or play - risk of fire !!!**

**if any of wires goes hot - double check connections, replace wires/connectors**

1. note temperature change (how many seconds/degree) on the hotbead
2. then increase voltage on psu (probably you have a led psu - so there is a small regulator next to the connectors)
3. validate if that help

Comment: Thanks!  It is a firmware problem. I had the extruder at 250c and bumped it up to 260c. It must have thought something was wrong and it set the temp to 0c. Unfortunately, it keeps printing. I made a quick and dirty enclosure with a few pieces of cardboard and then was able to get up to 110C for the bed and 255c for the extruder. So I guess I'm building an enclosure and will also upgrade the firmware to Marlin.

Comment: be very careful to maintain proper temperature inside the box as that could lead to elephant foot artifact (melted object at the hotbed).